# Jquery ui accordion collapses immediately after open on Ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

Jquery ui accordion works as intended on desktop, but on iPad when i click to expand, it does, but closes when open animation is finished.
When i set the collapsible to false the problem dissapears.

Any idea why this happens?

```
$(".accordionMobile").accordion({
    heightStyle: "content",
    collapsible: true,
    active: false
});

<div class="accordionMobile">                    
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <div class="content">
    <div>
    <h3 class="first-item">Annet</h3>
    <div class="content">
    <div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you have some mouseover stuff on h3, maybe?

Comment: Nope, no mouseover stuff. And that should effect desctop as well?